# Thatcher Style Headings and Subheadings in Memoir Class

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I'm typesetting my dissertation with the Memoir class, and I would like to use the Thatcher Chapter Style included in Memoir. However, I realized Memoir chapter styles only affect the title of chapters, and not the headings and subheadings.

Is there such a thing as a Thatcher style for these lower-level elements? If not, what would be the most efficient way of implementing them in Memoir?

Thanks!

-David

Comment: It's not clear what you would want them to look like. I assume you don't want "Section 1" on its own line followed a rule and a centred title.  But once you've decided, you need to use the regular `memoir` sectioning formatting tools to create centred titles. See e.g. p 94ff in the `memoir` manual, especially Example 6.1 (p. 98, code on p.97).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for the reference to Example 6.1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want your sectional titles centered to match the Thatcher chapterstyle then, following the code of example 6.1 in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`), try along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecheadstyle{\large\centering\MakeUppercase} % centered Uppercase section
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\centering} % centered small caps subsection
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\large\centering} % centered large subsubsection
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

It is up to you to decide what you think should be Thatcher styles for headings below `\chapter`, the above is just a suggestion, but `memoir` provides the tools for you to specify your own.